# Using Crypto-JS (SHA256) To Client Hash A Password

Tags: javascript, security, hash

I'm in the process of making a (relatively) insecure login page for my local LAN webserver, however, I don't want any passwords to be stored in plain text.

Code Is Below:

```
function validate(){
var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
var encrypted_password = CryptoJS.SHA256(password)
String(encrypted_password)
if ( username == "Username" && encrypted_password == "89e01536ac207279409d4de1e5253e01f4a1769e696db0d6062ca9b8f56767c8"){
    window.location = "dashboard/"
    return false;
}
else{
    alert("Your username or password was entered incorrectly.")
    return false;
}
```

}

For the purpose of demonstration, the correct username is "Username," and the hashed password is "mypassword".

What I want the Javascript to do:

1. Store the input of **username** and **password** in variables **username** and **password** respectively.
2. Store the hashed version of **password** in **encrypted_password**
3. Compare the **username** and **encrypted_password** variables to the correct answers, and if correct, forward the user on to dashboard/

However, even when "mypassword" is entered, and the hash is the same as that of the correct login code, it alerts me that the password was entered wrong. I think that this is an error in the way that I have stored the **encrypted_password** variable, however, I am not too sure.

*I should add (after some security conscious people commented on the faults of this design) that this project is for experimentation, and is a project for myself to learn more about the flaws of some cryptography solutions. Had this been a real production website, the flaws in its security would be quite obvious, I would imagine. Thanks again.*

Comment: Tried using `===` to ensure you're comparing types too?

Also, I wouldn't call this relatively insecure. I'd call it extremely insecure.

Comment: As you say, this is extremely insecure and basically nonsensical. Have you thought about slapping a Basic htpasswd authentication protection on your web server instead? At least that provides *actual* security instead of security theatre.

Comment: **DO NOT** do verification on the client side. This can make the server **VERY** insecure as hackers may bypass it easily by directly visiting "dashboard/" and the password may be leaked. You may try alert()-ing the output of SHA256 and checking for errors and beware that JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Comment: @christopher thanks for the help, I've just amended the question for the purpose of what I'm actually aiming for this project.

Comment: @deceze thanks for providing a solution. I've just amended the question for the purpose of what I'm actually aiming for this project

Comment: @HeWenYang thanks for the detailed reply. I've just edited the question to include the purpose of my project, don't worry, I'm aware that client side cryptography is never the best solution.

Comment: @Stephen I hope this will help: put a line of `alert(JSON.stringify({user:username,pass:password}));;` before the "if" line to see if the input matches the JavaScript code exactly. Beware of any spaces, cases, new-lines that don't match.